Induced map of the exterior power
enter image description here
I have a question regarding the proof in the picture (it is from "Lehrbuch der Mathematik, Band 4", Page 270 from Uwe Stroch and Hartmut Wiebe). It is stated that a linear map (f : V \to W ) induces a linear map form (T^n(f): T^n(V) \to T^n(W)) where T^n is the n-th tensor product. (you see the full proof in the picture). I don´t see how the map T^n(f) is induced.
I know that T^n is a functor but I am interested in the direct proof.

It's generally preferable to use MathJax instead of posting images, especially if the images are likely to induce brain aneurysms.

@blargoner I am new on Math stack exchange as you can probably see on my profile. So I was shocked by the rudeness of your comment, I thought this was a platform where you´re supposed to help each other. But the last part of your comment wasn´t at all. You could have provided some constructive feedback ... but no. I am new and don´t know the conventions around here so thank you for your tip with MathJax. But anyways I hope you have a good day! :)

The map
$$
  (v_1,\dotsc,v_n) \mapsto f(v_1)\otimes\dotsb\otimes f(v_n)
$$
is multilinear, so by the universal property of tensor powers there is a linear function, which we call $T^n(f)$, such that
$$
  T^n(f)(v_1\otimes\dotsb\otimes v_n) = f(v_1)\otimes\dotsb\otimes f(v_n).
$$

Thank you very much, this was very helpful. @nicholas todoroff
